# haskell GHCi cant import module

Tags: haskell, import, module

I'm having a weird problem.

I have a module, which is called "Compiler", the file itself is called compiler.hs.
If I try to import this module in another module (in the same directory), GHCi gives an error and says it cant find the file.
Now I have another module in the same directory, and works just fine when importing.

I use ghci program.hs to interpret the program. "program.hs" imports the compiler module.

My OS is a debian based linux distro and running GHCi, version 6.12.1:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `compiler.hs` to `Compiler.hs` (with upper case "C"). Linux file names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Haskell's Java-like requirement that module names/paths match file names is one of the few things about it that makes me sad.